# Lightbox in Wordpress Not Showing at Full Screen

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, elementor

I'm having issue with the media carousel player. I'm pulling in vimeo links to showcase my client's videos in the slideshow setting. When I press the play button to display the lightbox the window pops up extremely small and wide. How can I adjust this to make the lightbox video larger (full screen)?

Here's a video to explain the problem: https://www.loom.com/share/bf4a13f924934a2ca0a4b13fa7d4ccee?sid=4aa8b3b7-5995-4e65-a5fb-4333d142fe0c&fbclid=IwAR1iAR61rY2vW-EoAgJqr4tGGj3lVkqOjbwJT1AIhav0ieNADFCSM7yQ9FQ

Any help is appreciated!

I've tried the following...

--Deactivating and activating the plugins 1 by 1

--Turning off the minifying css in SG Optimizer

--Purging the SG cache

--Switching the theme

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code snippet  used to fix the issues:

.elementor-lightbox .elementor-video-container .elementor-video-landscape iframe, .elementor-lightbox .elementor-video-container .elementor-video-landscape video    { height: 100%;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS fixed it for me.

```
 .elementor-lightbox .elementor-video-container .elementor-video-landscape iframe, .elementor-lightbox .elementor-video-container .elementor-video-landscape video { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Mike Gais, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the WordPress Vimeo embed blocker or a plugin?  If it's a WordPress block try changing the settings in the bar that appears after selecting the block, [see here](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/vimeo-embed/).  Alternatively you could edit the css to make it bigger.

Comment: I was using the elementor video media widget to embed the video. I was able to successfully use the CSS code above to fix it.